# Multiple regex matching within a lookaround

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

i am trying to do a multiple match within a lookbehind and a look forward

Let's say i have the following string:

```
$ Hi, this is an example @
```

Regex: `(?<=$).+a.+(?=@)`

I am expecting it to return both 'a' within those boundaries, is there a way to do it with only one regex?

Engine: Python

Comment: Use the `\G` anchor.

Comment: `(?:\$|(?!^)\G)[^a]*\K(a)(?=.*?@)`  https://regex101.com/r/1BMCeK/1

Comment: What engine ? Usually if Python you have to capture between $-@ then process for `a`. Can only be a 2 step process. In Pythons _regex_  (not re) module you can use the \G anchor. These are your only options.

Comment: There is the finite multiple captures option if needed. Lets say there can only be a maximum of 10 a's in that string. `\$[^a]*(a)(?:[^a]*(a)(?:[^a]*(a)(?:[^a]*(a)(?:[^a]*(a)(?:[^a]*(a)(?:[^a]*(a)(?:[^a]*(a)(?:[^a]*(a)(?:[^a]*(a))?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?.*@` https://regex101.com/r/LDTEAP/1 You can do it that way .. If you need to restrict to only non $@ chars between, change `[^a]` to `[^a$@]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you can use quantifiers in the lookbehind**, use

```
(?<=\$[^$@]*?)a(?=[^@]*@)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/DfE2bQ/3).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \$                       '$'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^$@]*?                  any character except: '$' and '@' (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  a                        'a'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^@]*                    any character except: '@' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @                        '@'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

**PCRE pattern:**

```
(?:\G(?<!^)|\$)[^$]*?\Ka(?=[^@]*@)
```

See [another proof](https://regex101.com/r/DfE2bQ/4)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \G                       where the last m//g left off
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \$                       '$'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^$@]*?                  any character except: '$' and '@' (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       match reset operator
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  a                        'a'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^@]*                    any character except: '@' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @                        '@'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot, however regex101 says for my engine a lookbehind cannot contain quantifiers (Python) any workaround?

Comment: What engine Dot-Net, variable < asserets ? Why restrict with `[^$]` and `[^@]` ?

Comment: @CamiloPenagos No problem, install [this library](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and use any of the patterns.

Comment: @RyszardCzech The thing is i am using an API which i cannot alter it's backend, it's pure python, i just send the content and the expression.

Comment: @CamiloPenagos Then, I am sorry to say that, you are stuck.